# Python Requests module doesn't handle timeout if streams=True?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm fetching a batch of urls using the Python Requests module. I first want to read their headers only, to get the actual url and size of response. Then I get the actual content for any that pass muster.

So I use 'streams=True' to delay getting the content. This generally works fine.

But I'm encountering an occasional url that doesn't respond. So I put in timeout=3.

But those never time out. They just hang. If I remove the 'streams=True' it times out correctly. Is there some reason streams and timeout shouldn't work together? Removing the streams=True forces me to get all the content.

Doing this:

```
import requests
url = 'http://bit.ly/1pQH0o2'
x = requests.get(url) # hangs
x = requests.get(url, stream=True) # hangs
x = requests.get(url, stream=True, timeout=1) # hangs
x = requests.get(url, timeout=3) # times out correctly after 3 seconds
```

Comment: Which `requests` version are you using?

Comment: Using `requests` 2.5.1, `x = requests.get(url)` works just fine for me.

Comment: ah I'm using 2.2.1 , will upgrade thx

Answer (score 5):

There was a relevant github issue:

- [Timeouts do not occur when stream == True](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/1803)

The fix was [included into `requests==2.3.0` version](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/main/HISTORY.md#230-2014-05-16).

Tested it using the latest version - worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Do you close your responses? Unclosed and partially read responses can make multiple connections to the same resource and site may have connection limit for a single IP.

Comment: I have not been but will. tx